# .NET equivalent to Java Servlet and Apache Tomcat

Tags: .net, servlets

is there a .NET equivalent to Java Servlet and Apache Tomcat server?

A similar platform that will provide a means of deploying .NET "Servlets"-like?

Cheers.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

IIS *IS* the equivelent to Apache Tomcat, and ASP.NET WebServices or WCF are the equivelent of Servlets.  IIS is both a web server and an application server.

Technically, Servlets are more low level than web services, but that's because Servlets are a spcific API, and Web Services are typically implemented on top of Servlets. .net doesn't support the Servlet API, but you can use third party products if you need to use that API specifically.

Comment: I see, it would cost me to buy third party products to use the Servlet API in .net

Comment: @xybrek - Who said anything about cost?  It's just not included with .Net because it's not generally needed.  Servlet API is specific to Java, because it was created at a time when there was no such thing as Web Services.

Comment: well I first thought of "third-party products" in the MS world as paid products. From what you say its not the case, then can you share me some link if possible, so I can check it. Up to this moment Java servlet is a powerful piece of technology, this is why I am looking forward in doing such thing in the .NET platform.

Comment: @xybrek - Why would you think that?  There's easily as much open source in the MS world as there is in the Java world.  Anything not included in the Java distribution is a third party product.  An example of a Servlet API for .net is http://othelloservlet.sourceforge.net .  I still don't understand why you want to write to the Servlet API when anything you can do in a servlet, you can do in a web service.

Comment: @Mysere Man, anyway, I don't want to write Servlet API in .NET I just need to create similar solution I have made with servlet like, web counters, filters and proxy...

Answer (score 1):

well, .NET has ASP.NET which runs server side and allows you to do a lot of things. Normally ASP.NET runs on IIS on a Windows Server and you have plenty of tools to create your architecture (WCF, WF, MSMQ, Windows Services, Scheduled Tasks...).

Is there anything special like a certain feature of the Java servlet(s) you are thinking about right now? You should ask more specific questions because being so general, answers are general too :)

Comment: Yah, sorry about that. Technically I want to implement with .net what I have implemented with using servlets, filters, counters, proxy etc.